# Python: Extracting lines from a file using another file as key

Tags: python, extract, lines

I have a 'key' file that looks like this (MyKeyFile):

afdasdfa ghjdfghd wrtwertwt asdf (these are in a column, but I never figured out the formatting, sorry)

I call these keys and they are identical to the first word of the lines that I want to extract from a 'source' file. So the source file (MySourceFile) would look something like this (again, bad formatting, but 1st column = the key, following columns = data):

afdasdfa (several tab delimited columns)
.
.
ghjdfghd ( several tab delimited columns)
.
wrtwertwt
.
.
asdf

And the '.' would indicate lines of no interest currently.

I am an absolute novice in Python and this is how far I've come:

```
with open('MyKeyFile','r') as infile, \
open('MyOutFile','w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        for runner in source:
            # pick up the first word of the line in source
            # if match, print the entire line to MyOutFile
            # here I need help
outfile.close()
```

I realize there may be better ways to do this. All feedback is appreciated - along my way of solving it, or along more sophisticated ones.

Thanks
jd

Comment: what format are these files (.csv, .txt, .tsv etc.)?

Comment: Mike, they are .csv files. The source file has some 30 columns and is tab formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood (corrent me in the comments if I am wrong), you have 3 files:

1. MySourceFile
2. MyKeyFile
3. MyOutFile

And you want to:

1. Read keys from MyKeyFile
2. Read source from MySourceFile
3. Iterate over lines in the source
4. If line's first word is in keys: append that line to MyOutFile
5. Close MyOutFile

So here is the Code:

```
with open('MySourceFile', 'r') as sourcefile:
    source = sourcefile.read().splitlines()

with open('MyKeyFile', 'r') as keyfile:
    keys = keyfile.read().split()

with open('MyOutFile', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in source:
        if line.split():
            if line.split()[0] in keys:
                outfile.write(line + "\n")
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. You got my problem solved. Appreciated that. There is an issue of optimization I guess. Source file is significantly larger than the key file and I suppose it would matter how the iterations go. Anyway, I'll get my stuff done here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that this would be a cleaner way of doing it, assuming that your "key" file is called "key_file.txt" and your main file is called "main_file.txt"

```
keys = []
my_file = open("key_file.txt","r") #r is for reading files, w is for writing to them.
for line in my_file.readlines():
    keys.append(str(line)) #str() is not necessary, but it can't hurt
#now you have a list of strings called keys. 
#take each line from the main text file and check to see if it contains any portion of a given key. 

my_file.close()
new_file = open("main_file.txt","r")
for line in new_file.readlines():
    for key in keys:
        if line.find(key) > -1: 
            print "I FOUND A LINE THAT CONTAINS THE TEXT OF SOME KEY", line
```

You can modify the print function or get rid of it to do what you want with the desired line that contains the text of some key. Let me know if this works

Comment: Hi Ajax,Thanks for your prompt reply. Unfortunately, your code did not do what I wanted. I might have been unclear in posing my question. In that case, I apologize.